# Can't get latest updates

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, bitbucket

I using Git with Bitbucket - every time when I have this issues I deleted my files from local PC and copied it from bitbucket. I think it isn't good idea do it every time.
What happened: usually for correct work I did next step - update my branch for last version and after that I commited my updates in my Branch. Before I got this problem - I didn't get latest updatets, because someone did several changes in my Branch without me. As result I tried to commit changes from my PC and couldn't do it.

Now I wanna delete outgoing commit and try to get update, how can I do it? (I tried do: click on my commit->Reset->Reset and delete changes (nothing happens)/ and I tried: action-> view history->find my commit and click on a reset ->Delete changes(nothing happens)).How can i delete outgoing commit?

[image]

Comment: You should just pull their changes and merge them into yours and then push the new changes. This is how distributed version control works. There is always a bit of a coordination exercise when two or more people update the same branch. Merging involves reading their changes, understanding the effects on your changes and sorting out any bugs that have arisen. It keeps you up to date with what they did to the code so you know better how to code it going forward

Comment: Thanks, I tried do it. I had a conflict. After I resolved it I can't pull their changes and merge with my

Comment: Well, you can, but you'll need to resolve the conflict. I can't remember exactly how VS does conflict resolution because it's been a long time since I used it as a git client. Take a look at something like https://dzone.com/articles/git-operations-with-visual-studio-part-2 - after the conflict is resolved then your changes are merged with theirs so you're ready to check the code and push it

Comment: Execute `git stash && git pull && git stash apply` then resolve conflicts.

IMO: learn git and use console commands. Editors are okay-ish, but a button labeld with 'rebase' might not do what you expect it to do. As said: my opinion, i do not want to start a religious war here ;)